# (How) can I possibly "miss a signal" with this ConcurrentLinkedQueue and sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

In my Java application, several threads put data in a queue from which another thread (just one) takes objects and dispatches them.

Occasionally, the consuming thread seems to not notice that new items have been added to the queue, as the log messages indicating a poll cease to appear. Log messages from the producing threads indicate that these items do indeed arrive. Googling some taught me that this seems to be known as "missed signal". Since I'm neither `wait`ing nor using locks, I'm not sure if this applies to me.

What really puzzles me is that when I interrupt the consumer thread, it processes all items in the queue and then stays silent again, without ever exiting.

Here's the main loop of the consumer thread, the producer threads do stuff like reading from sockets and their only common thing is that they use `add()` on the queue from which the consumer is polling.

```
public class FieldFrontService
{
    // ...

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Transmission> _qRec;

    // ...

    private Runnable _createReceptionist()
    {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Transmission tx = FieldFrontService.this._qRec.poll();
                    if (null == tx) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        FieldFrontService.this._receiveTransmission(tx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is it a caching thing? Does _qRec need to be volatile?

Comment: I got great answers that help *me* in my particular situation, thanks to everybody. I feel, however, that this thread still lacks some answer on why the code above doesn't work, to be more generally useful. This might be my fault, I'll think about what I can do to improve this.

Comment: I think my main suggestion would be to use a shared variable as a stop flag rather than using interrupts.

Comment: For starters, you don't wait via sleep unless you truly know what you do. Flow control via Thread.interrupt() is possible not very easy to get it right. Using CLQ for the sort of the thing you attempt is great and beats any use of Executor/blocking queue when done right for cases like one consumer/many producers.

Comment: But we don't have explanation of the reason here.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are better off using an ExecutorService which combines a Thread pool and a Queue. Also it works. ;)

```
public class FieldFrontService {
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    void receiveTransmission(final Transmission tx) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                FieldFrontService.this._receiveTransmission(tx);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this code... But we still don't know why Hanno Fietz code doesn't work as intented.

Comment: Nice. I had a thread pool in place in older version, but that raised a bunch of concurrency issues without any benefits from parallel processing, so I ditched it. Having a "pool" with only one thread didn't even occur to me. Duh. Still, Nicolas is right, I'm no smarter on the missed insertions.

Comment: @Hanno, based on your code sample, you might want to have a scheduled task that holds the contents of your loop rather than a bigger task that wraps a while-loop around the meat of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think your InterruptedException is getting eaten somewhere in your call stack.

This pattern is what concerns me:

```
try {                             
    Thread.sleep(250);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    break;
}
```

If you are using a similar pattern in your code, that the thread interrupted state was lost.  For example, if `Thread.interrupted()` were used in your call stack, that will [reset the interrupted status of your thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29).  As a result, your while loop will never exit: the status was reset to false.

These two lines are the points of concern:

```
Transmission tx = FieldFrontService.this._qRec.poll();
// ....
FieldFrontService.this._receiveTransmission(tx);
```

If either of those calls makes a call to `Thread.currentThread().interrupted()`, you will lose the `isInterrupted` boolean.  I would look over the implementation of both of those methods in case the Exception / state is being consumed.

My handling of InterruptedExceptions is different.  I prefer to rethrow the interrupt:

```
try {                             
    Thread.sleep(250);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

That way, I ensure that there is no possibility that my interrupt was lost.  Basically, I'm trying to say, no, seriously, STOP Thread STOP!

Comment: Good point about the InterruptedException being eaten, although I have serious trouble imagining where that could be (I left nothing out, the code is straight from my IDE). I'll investigate, though.

Comment: @Hanno, I'll add some notes to the answer to point out where I'd be worried.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not because the break statement exits the while loop, causing the thread to stop? What happens if you remove the break statement? Or is that what you expect?

I'm suggesting the thread doesn't see the new items, because the thread has already stopped due to an exception you didn't expect.

Comment: The thread does *not* stop. In my particular situation, that actually mitigates the damage, because I can interrupt the thread and then the queue is processed (sic). It does, however, confuse the heck out of me, whenever I try to find out why it doesn't seem to poll anything from the queue.

Comment: I find it very strange that it never stops. I wonder what happens to the code if the interrupt occurs outwith the sleep block. I think the best thing is to avoid using interrupt.