# Does a break leave just the try/catch or the surrounding loop?

Tags: java

If I have a `try ... catch` block inside a `while` loop, and there#s a `break` inside the `catch`, does program execution leave the loop?

As in:

```
while (!finished) {
    try {
        doStuff();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Will an exception thrown in doStuff() exit the loop?

Comment: I was sure that I would leave the loop, but another problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910529/how-can-i-possibly-miss-a-signal-with-this-concurrentlinkedqueue-and-sleep) lead me to believe that I might be mistaken. The basic Java tutorials don't mention `try`/`catch`, just loops and `switch`. I'm a little astonished that such a basic thing has me confused.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, it will. Easiest way to find out is to try it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        while (i<10) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                if(i ==7){
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("out of loop");
    }
```

It will print

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
out of loop
```

The output starts with 0.

Comment: Thanks for the hands-on answer. I had my mind in theory mode. :) I'm still surprised that I didn't find any boring tech document which says "break will jump out of the following blocks: ..." since it wouldn't work with a `switch`, and my code acted strangely, I thought maybe this would work like `pass` in Python when inside a `catch`.

Comment: depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Easiest way to find out is really to google this answer though

Answer (score 33):

A `break` statement always applies to the innermost `while`, `do`, or `switch`, regardless of other intervening statements. However, there is *one* case where the `break` will not cause the loop to exit:

```
while (!finished) {
    try {
        doStuff();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    } finally {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Here, the abrupt completion of the `finally` is the cause of the abrupt completion of the `try`, and the abrupt completion of the `catch` is lost.

Comment: @fmucar: Thanks. I should have noted that this applies to *unlabeled* `break` statements, though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it'll break the loop.

But why not do:

```
finished = true;
```

instead?

Comment: That code is completely made up to illustrate the question. Of course, in real code, I could just set the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `break` exists loop and `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

> Will an exception thrown in doStuff()
>   exit the loop?

Step by step, here is what will happen:

1. The exception is thrown in doStuff()
2. Your "eat all Exceptions" handler will catch the exception.
3. The "break" statement will leave the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It does. break exit from while loop.