# How to break a loop if action freezes for a long time

Tags: java, protocols, irc

Actually, I'm writing on Java (if it's a big deal and java has specific methods to solve my problem, I don't know, to be honest) an IRC protocol Client, and have a little lack of knowledge. I have a line where I read line from IRC server. That line is:

**line = reader.readLine();**

It works fine, I'm using this line in a loop, but application freeze on this line if server doesn't send anything. My question is, how I am able to break my loop if, for instance, server doesn't send anything for 10 seconds?

I tried to do this

```
do {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    line = reader.readLine();
    ... //doing other actions
    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 10*1000);
```

And it works only when I get next response from server... I can't break loop after 10 seconds waiting, with my method it will wait forever if server doesn't send anything. That's my problem, sorry if too many mistakes or useless text, it's my first question here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Socket.setSoTimeOut](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29). you can have a `SocketTimeoutException` after the timeout.

Comment: I'd suggest including a link to this answer, since it answers the other part of the question (how to break out of the loop) http://stackoverflow.com/a/5910875/4602283

Comment: Thank you, looks good, tried to use it now, but started to get IOException somehow. I hope I'll solve this problem, because your method looks really clear for this situation:) As I think, good way to break my loop would be in catch, of this exception, block. Please, correct me If I'm definitely wrong

Comment: you can update your question with the new changes with this method.. aand post the problem you are facing

Comment: Thank you. If I will do this after several days, will anybody see it?

Comment: you can add as new question if you have any problem .. else you can update and comment here. in the meantime if you think the answer was helpful you can upvote/accept it

Comment: When I will get enough reputation, I precisely upvote this answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use multi-threading features of Java.

The wait and read process of your application should be performed by a distinct thread that you have to explicitly create.
Another thread should handle the application UI.

In this way the wait and read process will not freeze the application any longer.

The [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class is a good start.
You could for example do it to create and start a thread :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        do {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            line = reader.readLine();
            ... //doing other actions
            } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 10*1000);
    };
};
thread.start();
```

---

**Edit after comments.**

You could use `setSoTimeout()` as StinePike has suggested but it will not be enough as you should reset the timeout to `0` (it means infinite) or any value desirable for you when the operation requiring a timeout was terminated.
Otherwise the timeout will also apply to other reading that don't want this restricted timeout.

```
do {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // you set the timeout for reading to 10 second for each reading
    socket.setSoTimeout(10*1000);
    try{
      line = reader.readLine();
      ... //doing other actions 
      }
    catch (SocketException e){
        // processing if the timeout occurs and break
        break;
    } 
 } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < 10*1000);

 // you reinit the timeout for reading to infinite or any value desirable for you
 socket.setSoTimeout(0);
```

Comment: I understand that I can start timer in thread to count time of each loop iteration, but how can I break loop in class method if thread timer > 10 seconds? Should I think something around thread synchronization?

Comment: No the thread here should be used as a background task that waits for messages from the server. Why do you want break the loop ? It you break it you will not receive any messages from server any longer. A server can send a message at a time, stop sending some seconds and start again.

Comment: Actually I have a Thread that waits for messages from server, and also I use synchronize, when I'm using this method I make my thread (that always waiting for messages) "wait". Because in thread I only get raw messages, but I use this method when I need to process returned codes (specific, depends on command sent) by server

Comment: Do you mean that if the code is not sent within the 10 seconds, you want to cancel this processing ?

Comment: Exactly! I want to break my loop then and it will return some result and also notify (start again) my thread

Comment: Thanks a lot, this way looks much better for my problem!