# Puppeteer - Handlin page.waitForSelector() fails

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

If `page.waitForSelector()` fails, it throws an error. Since this is run inside an async function if leads straight to the catch portion of the code.

Is there a chance that if `page.waitForSelector()` fails, code is executed one line below?

Like this (pseudocode):

```
if ( (await page.waitForSelector('.test') == null) { //do X}
```

From the API:

> If the selector doesn't appear after the timeout milliseconds of waiting, the function will throw.

How do i manage that throw in the same block of code, as if the fucntion would succeed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

why don't you catch the error which `page.waitForSelector` is throwing and do your actions after that something like this -

```
(async() => {

     try {
        page.waitForSelector(selector);
     } catch(error) {
       // do as you wish with this error and then do your next actions

           try {
                page.goto('someUrl');
           } catch(error) {
               throw new Error(error);
           }
     }

})
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know i could put it inside a try catch block. My page.waitForSelector() is inside a while loop. In case the waitForSelector() fails, i want the while loop to break;. Just that. Will the break for the while loop work, if the break is declared inside a catch block?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Please see this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910817/does-a-break-leave-just-the-try-catch-or-the-surrounding-loop/5910875

Comment: Excellent aswer. Than you very much!

Answer (score 2):

What I do to detect if the selector is present inside loops like that is:

```
if (await page.$('.test')) {
  break
}
```

Keep in mind that after that, you don't need to `waitForSelector` or any `waitFor`, because you already know that this selector is present, so just continue the program, as I did below:

(Just for demonstration purposes, don't use it like this... If the website has any "bot protection", it's gonna drop you off after the second reload, probably you want to add some timeout for this, to emulate the user timing for reloads: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))`, before the reload)

```
while(true) {
    if (await page.$('.test')) {
      break
    }
    page.reload()
}

page.click('.test')
```